# Mongoose - persistent `virtual` field?

Tags: node.js, model, mongoose, virtual

Ok, I have node as backend, it has the following Mongoose model:

```
var SomeSchema = new Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  iplanned: {type: String, default:60}
});

SomeSchema.virtual('planned')
.get(function () {
  return parseInt(this.iplanned / 60, 10) + ' mins';
})
.set(function (val) {
  this.iplanned = parseInt(val, 10) * 60;
});

someModel = mongoose.model('Some', SomeSchema);
```

So far it is good, from node.js side of things I can work with the records and access this `planned` field as I like.

The following is a simple responder to serve this list through http:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
  someModel.find(function (err, deeds) {
    return res.send(deeds);
  });
});
```

And here's the problem - the virtual field `planned` is not included in each record (well, it is understandable, sort of). Is there a way to inject somehow my virtual field to each record? Or I have to do the `virtual` conversion on a front end as well? (Yeah, I know that there's Meteor.js out there, trying go without it here).

Comment: Is there a pattern to when the virtual field is not included? What does you data look like in mongo?

Comment: As schema (above) suggests, Mongo stores records of {name, iplanned}. For the sake of application, virtual `planned` field was created - a simple formatter in this case.

Answer (score 1):

In your schema you should redefine **toJSON()** method:

```
SomeSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
   var obj = this.toObject();
   obj.planned = this.planned;
   return obj;
};
```